# Using SharpSvn to retrieve log entries within a date range

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

I'm using [SharpSvn](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2008/04/sharpsvn-brings.html) to interact with my svn repository via C# code.  I am using this code to retrieve svn log entries:

```
Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logitems;
var uri = new Uri("http://myserver/svn/foo/bar.txt");
client.GetLog(uri, out logitems);
foreach (var logentry in logitems)
{
    string author = logentry.Author;
    string message = logentry.LogMessage;
    DateTime checkindate = logentry.Time;
}
```

This works well, but now I want to restrict the returned log entries by revision date.  This is something that can be done via the svn command line with something like

```
svn log "http://myserver/svn/foo/bar.txt" --revision {2008-01-01}:{2008-12-31}
```

I can't seem to figure out a parallel capability within SharpSvn.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
DateTime startDateTime = // ...;
DateTime endDateTime = // ...;
SvnRevisionRange range = new SvnRevisionRange(new SvnRevision(startDateTime), new SvnRevision(endDateTime));
client.GetLog(uri, new SvnLogArgs(range), out logitems);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I missed the fact that SvnRevision could take a DateTime in its constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* you might be able to do it using one of the `GetLog` function that takes a `SharpSvn.SvnLogArgs` parameter.

```
public bool GetLog(System.Uri target, SharpSvn.SvnLogArgs args,
        out System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection logItems)
```

That class has `Start`/`End` that are `SharpSvn.SvnRevision` objects which *look* like they can take a "time" parameter.

I've only done a little bit with it, but that would be where you could start looking.