# How to get a list of revision using sharpsvn

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

How do I get a list of revisions from sharpsvn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the metadata for `SvnLogEventArgs` (which is returned as a collection from `GetLog`) it derives from `SvnLoggingEventArgs`, which has properties of Author, Revision, Time and LogMessage (amongst others)

Each `SvnLogEventArgs` item has a collection of `ChangedPaths`, which have properties for SvnChangeAction, and Path.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of all the log info by this method:

```
var client = new SvnClient();

System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logEventArgs;

client.GetLog("targetPath", out logEventArgs);
```

Iterating through all the logEventArgs will give you some useful information - LogMessage, Author, etc.

---

I don't know what you're doing, but I am checking the latest version of the working copy using SvnWorkingCopyClient:

```
var workingCopyClient = new SvnWorkingCopyClient();

SvnWorkingCopyVersion version;

workingCopyClient.GetVersion(workingFolder, out version);
```

The latest version of the local working repository is then available through

```
long localRev = version.End;
```

For a remote repository, use

```
 var client = new SvnClient();

 SvnInfoEventArgs info;

 client.GetInfo(targetUri, out info);

 long remoteRev = info.Revision;
```

instead.

This is similar to using the `svnversion` tool from the command line.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!It helped me much and answered exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing at what your question really is about the answer is most likely SvnClient.Log(), to get you a list of changes of a path.

Another anwer would be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
  yield return i;
```

to get you the first 100 revisisions of a repository ;-)

See [Using SharpSvn to retrieve log entries within a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989034/using-sharpsvn-to-retrieve-log-entries-within-a-date-range) for some examples on how to use SvnClient.Log()

Comment: lol, fair enough.  I gues what I'm after is the meta for a revision, the commit comment, which files were changed etc

Answer (score 0):

This is the code form which you can get all the revisions no in list revisions numbers. UriSCpath will be uri for svn path.

```
 SvnTarget tr = SvnTarget.FromUri(UriSCPath);
                Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logEventArgs;
                List<Int64> revisionNumbers = new List<Int64>();
                SvnLogArgs logArgs = new SvnLogArgs();
                DPISVN_Clnt.GetLog(UriSCPath, logArgs, out logEventArgs);

                Int64 latestReision = logEventArgs[0].Revision;

                foreach (var item in logEventArgs)
                {
                        revisionNumbers.Add(item.Revision);

                }
```